# I'm having a hard time getting some elements to resize in JavaFX

Tags: java, math, javafx, resize

I have a series of elements I wish to resize dynamically.

I have a small `StackPane` set within a larger `AnchorPane`. The `AnchorPane` resizes based on the window size changing. I am trying to resize the `StackPane` to stay the same size relative to the size it was before the `AnchorPane` resized.

Basically, if my `AnchorPane` is 1000px and my `Stackpane` is 100px, if the `AnchorPane` enlarges to 1200px, my `StackPane` should be 120px.

```
ChangeListener parentResized = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> oe, Number oldVal, Number newVal) {
        double diffBetween = sc.getWidth() / parent.getWidth();
        double toAdd = (newVal.doubleValue() - oldVal.doubleValue()) * diffBetween;
        sc.setPrefWidth(sc.getWidth() + toAdd);
    }
};
```

I cannot work out how to do this using my `ChangeListener`; the `oldVal`/`newVal` updates very quickly.

I am getting an odd issue where it seems to resize properly upon widening, however if I drag slowly enough when narrowing, the element doesn't resize at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) for these kind of requirements. Bind the height and width of the `StackPane` to that of the `AnchorPane`.

For binding the `StackPane's` *width* and *height* to exactly 1/10th of that of AnchorPane, you can use the following :

```
stackPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty().divide(10));
stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty().divide(10));
```

I have created a MCVE where the StackPane's height and width is 1/10th of that of the AnchorPane. There are labels which show the current size of both the layouts.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Labels for AnchorPane's size
        Label apHeight = new Label();
        Label apWidth = new Label();

        // Labels for StackPane's size
        Label spHeight = new Label();
        Label spWidth = new Label();

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color : CORNSILK");
        anchorPane.setPrefSize(500, 500);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color : AQUA");
        stackPane.getChildren().add(new VBox(spWidth, spHeight));

        // Add labels and StackPane to AnchorPane
        VBox box = new VBox(apHeight, apWidth);
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(box, stackPane);

        // Set StackPane location in AnchorPane
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(stackPane, 200.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(stackPane, 200.0);

        // Listeners for updating the Label
        anchorPane.widthProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> apWidth.setText("Width : " + String.valueOf(newValue)));
        anchorPane.heightProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> apHeight.setText("Height : " + String.valueOf(newValue)));

        stackPane.widthProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> spWidth.setText("W : " + String.valueOf(newValue)));
        stackPane.heightProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> spHeight.setText("H : " + String.valueOf(newValue)));

        // Bind StackPane's Height and Width to that of AnchorPane's
        stackPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty().divide(10));
        stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty().divide(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll let you know how this goes, but this is very promising. The example is a bit narrow; in actual fact the `StackPane` is user re-sizeable and should therefore stay at whatever fraction of the `AnchorPane` it currently happens to be. I will mark this as an answer however!

Comment: so I implemented this and it worked as I wanted it to, but as I suspected, when resizing the `StackPane` I ran into trouble. I unbound the property, made my changes but when I rebound it, chaos. I'm considering posting another question, actually.

Comment: Well, yes, you can post another question. Make sure, you add a link to this question.